# Discovering local Bluetooth devices many times on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android

Dear Android developers,

I have developed an app (in XAMARIN) which discovers all the Bluetooth devices in the range. It works fine. However, I need to do the discovery 100 times in order to obtain good data for an experiment. I initiate the discovery every 30 seconds. The problem is that the app always breaks down after 19 "measurements" and the debugger can not handle the error.

Important parts of my code:

Firstly, I register the BluetoothReceiver in OnStart() method in MainActivity:

```
RegisterReceiver(bluetoothDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
```

I initiate BluetoothAdapter in MainActivity

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
```

This method is called when the devices are discovered

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Devices found");
        string action = intent.Action;

        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
            short rssi = intent.GetShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraRssi, (short)0);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newDevice.Name);

        }
    }
```

Every 30 seconds, this line of code is called

```
adapter.StartDiscovery();
```

I tired to unregister the Bluetooth Receiver and turn on and turn off device's Bluetooth (in the code). It did not help.

Thank you for any feedback.

// Edit

I found this stack trace on MAC Visual Studio:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9oT4PKLRpTMd3o2UTludjVzWjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What or which error do you see in the Application Output window?

Comment: Basically - UnhandledException event

Comment: Are you able to get a stack trace?

Comment: A stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please explain me how the Stack Trace works in XAMARIN? I can put  this line somewhere into the code:             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Environment.StackTrace); When the app stop working, I just see this comment in Visual Studio: An unhandled exception occurred. Nothing appears in the Android Debug Bridge.

Comment: The mistake was not in the Bluetooth functionality. It was caused by a timer. Solved.